# XSLT copy same siblings until other sibling appear

Tags: xml, xslt

Hei,

i am trieing to Transform following list using XSLT 1.0:

```xml
<div data-class="a"/>
<div data-class="b"/>
<div data-class="b"/>
<div data-class="c"/>
<div data-class="b"/>
<div data-class="a"/>
<div data-class="b"/>
<div data-class="c"/>
<div data-class="d"/>
<div data-class="a"/>
<div data-class="a"/>
```

It should transform the data as following:

```xml
<div data-class="a">
    <div data-class="b"/>
    <div data-class="b">
        <div data-class="c"/>
    </div>
    <div data-class="b"/>
</div>
<div data-class="a">
    <div data-class="b">
        <div data-class="c">
            <div data-class="d"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-class="a"/>
<div data-class="a"/>
    <div data-class="b">
        <div data-class="c"/>
        <div data-class="c"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trieing to transform it correctly since hours. 
To transform it, i am using the copy tags:

```xml
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@data-class='a']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* | following-sibling::div[@data-class='b']" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@data-class='a']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::div[@data-class='b']" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@dataclass='b']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::div[@data-class='c']" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that all following elements of the data-class are taken - please help me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there some logic in the hierarchy? Or does one have to explicitly put `b` under `a`, `c` under `b`, and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="b" match="div[@data-class='b']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::div[@data-class='a'][1])" />
<xsl:key name="c" match="div[@data-class='c']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::div[@data-class='b'][1])" />
<xsl:key name="d" match="div[@data-class='d']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::div[@data-class='c'][1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@data-class='a']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@data-class='a']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('b', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@data-class='b']">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('c', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@data-class='c']">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('d', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above is applied to the following **well-formed** input example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <div data-class="a"/>
    <div data-class="b"/>
    <div data-class="b"/>
    <div data-class="c"/>
    <div data-class="b"/>
    <div data-class="a"/>
    <div data-class="b"/>
    <div data-class="c"/>
    <div data-class="d"/>
    <div data-class="a"/>
    <div data-class="a"/>
</root>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <div data-class="a">
      <div data-class="b"/>
      <div data-class="b">
         <div data-class="c"/>
      </div>
      <div data-class="b"/>
   </div>
   <div data-class="a">
      <div data-class="b">
         <div data-class="c">
            <div data-class="d"/>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div data-class="a"/>
   <div data-class="a"/>
</root>
```